# cordova-plugin-camera-preview performance

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I've been developing an iOS app on Cordova which makes use of the cordova-plugin-camera-preview plugin. This plugin provides in-app camera preview and capture functionality, unlike the built-in plugin which redirects to the ios camera application.

This plugin works well for me, except for one thing: after takePicture() is called, my app freezes for about 10 seconds. I've traced this down to the point where the plugin is returning the base64 image data to my Cordova application. The images are only about 150k, so I can't imagine it's the image size that's causing a problem.

Does anyone know if there is a solution to this? Alternatively, is anyone aware of a replacement plugin which provides the same functionality?

For reference, my code is simple:

```
let options = {
    height: 500,
    width: 667,
    quality: 85
  }

console.log('taking picture')
CameraPreview.takePicture(options, (base64PictureData) => {
      console.log('picture taken')
      let base64Url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64PictureData
      ... do something with data
  })
```

The log consistently shows about 10-15 seconds between the above to console log entries.

Comment: are you targeting iOS and Android? if you only target Android, you can use getUserMedia to get the camera feed and put it inside a video tag. If you target iOS, there aren't other plugins as far as I know

Comment: I'm targeting ios only.

Comment: Then no luck, I think that’s the only one